# How to find a specific string in a stream socket byte stream

Tags: c

I am new to C and am having a little trouble here I am attempting to parse through an html file and count the number of p-tags within the file. I am using different size chunks, the size being input by the user. But when the size jumps to 200 I get the wrong number of p-tags. I use the recv function to receive a file and am using the content of the buffer in order to count said p-tags.

```
    count = recv(s, buf, sizeof buf, 0);
    for(int i=0; i<chunk; i++)
    {
        if(buf[i]=='<')
          if(buf[i+1]=='p')
                if(buf[i+2]=='>')
                pcount++;>*/
    }
```

when the chunk size is 200 it should return 13 p-tags but it returns 15.

Comment: What is `chunk`? How is it related to `count` as returned by `recv`? Will the indexes `i + 1` and `i + 2` be valid when `i` is equal to `chunk - 1` or `chunk - 2`? And please try to create a proper [mcve] to show us. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: While processing the file, I must do so in chunks whose size in Bytes is determined by the user through a command line argument. Count has to do with another part of the program where I return the number of bytes in the html file.

Comment: Then what happens if `count < chunk`? If you're using TCP sockets remember that there are no message boundaries or packets. The data received in a single `recv` call could be less than what was sent in a single `send` call, or even more if two or more `send` calls was buffered before you calling `recv`. And the indexes `i + 1` and `i + 2` *will* go out of bounds of the `chunk` size. And you don't even seem to be checking for errors, which is a very important part of socket communication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems. Presumably `chunk` is the size of the buffer. Now, if `recv` is successful it will return the number of bytes received. You should use *this* count instead of `chunk` for limiting the loop. Otherwise you'd run the loop for even a failed `recv` operation and it would count whatever garbage existed in the buffer.

The second problem of course is that the `<p>` tag might actually be located on the border of 2 chunks.

The third one is that you're probably reading the buffer out of bounds - even if `buf[i]` is valid doesn't mean that `buf[i + 2]` is.

---

The *simplest*, but perhaps not the most correct solution would be to use `fdopen` on the socket, and then `fgetc()`, or reading the *entire body* into a buffer. Let's use `fdopen` though:

```
FILE *f = fdopen(s, "r+b");
size_t pcount = 0;

int c = 0;
while (c != EOF)
{
    if ((c = fgetc(f)) == '<' 
         && (c = fgetc(f)) == 'p'
         && (c = fgetc(f)) == '>') 
    {
        pcount += 1;
    }
}
```

Here we're wrapping the socket into a `<stdio.h>` `FILE`; `fgetc` returns the next character from the file and the `&&` short-circuits; the return value of last `fgetc` is captured in `c` as well; and if the return value was `EOF` the loop is broken and `pcount` will contain the correct tag count.

If you cannot use `fdopen`, then you can write your own buffering logic for the socket, or even make a simulated function that calls `recv` for one byte at a time...

---

Or you can use a state machine:

```
int pstate = 0;

ssize_t count = recv(s, buf, sizeof buf, 0);
// TODO: add error checking...

for (ssize_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if (buf[i] == '<') {
        pstate = 1;
    }
    else if (pstate == 1 && buf[i] == 'p') {
        pstate = 2;
    }
    else if (pstate == 2 && buf[i] == '>') {
        pcount += 1;
        pstate = 0;
    }
    else {
        // if any other character is found,
        // or any of these characters was in wrong position
        // then reset the state
        pstate = 0;
    }
}
```

This will work correctly across different chunk sizes and does not address the buffer out of bounds. As a complication though, it does look much more complicated compared to the `fdopen` one, even though it is still missing the outer loop!

Comment: @RaqueldeAnda if you need to use a specific chunk size, then the state machine thing is perhaps the one you should use